# Regarding permission to add a download saved list template in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a list that I want to copy to different site collection. What I did is to

1. save list as template
2. Download the template
3. Upload the template to the _catalog/lt/Forms in different site collection
   In this step I get I dont have access.

This seems a bit weird.

1. I have the SharePoint admin permission
2. In the site collection which I am about to upload the list template, I have Full control permission and I also created the site collection.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

- Is the list you are attempting to save as a template using a feature that isn't activated in your new collection?
- Have you tried saving a list as a template in the new collection to see if the error is present for template saves as well as uploads?
- Could you or your users use the new Modern experience to create a list from an existing list as a workaround?  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-new-list-based-on-the-columns-in-another-list-49666e8c-8c48-414f-8e5e-dc0e232acd27